# Are the two interference patterns at the output of an interferometer quantum entangled?

Tags: quantum-entanglement, interference, interferometry

When an interferometer creates an interference pattern a second interference pattern is always created. The two patterns are opposites of each other. Knowing one pattern lets me accurately predict the other pattern 100% of the time. I have found this to be true in Michelson, Mach Zehnder, Sagnac, Fabry and even double slit interferometers. I understand that conservation of energy is the reason that is given for this. My question: Is quantum entanglement the underlying process? Are the two interference patterns quantum entangled?

Comment: You have the same effect when you send classical light on an interferometer. No entanglement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes (**see edit below** though).

The two interference patterns are quantum entangled, meaning they are described by a *single* and common state vector.

If a single photon hits a beam-splitter, it can be either reflected to path $a$ or transmitted to path $b$:

[image]

However, you cannot describe the two paths as (classically) independent and unrelated. The beam splitter has connected the two paths, it has *entangled them*, for what occurs on one of them (e.g. a measurement) also affects what occurs on the other one. No matter the distance, even if they are separated by light years.

So you should write the full state as
$$ |\Psi\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2} \cdot \left ( \,\,\, |1\rangle_a \otimes |0\rangle_b + |0\rangle_a \otimes |1\rangle_b \,\,\,\right  ) ,$$

where $|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle$ mean having one or zero photons. 
 Paths $a$ and $b$ are entangled because you cannot spit this state vector in $( ... )_a \otimes (...)_b$, which would allow you to treat them separately.

---

**EDIT**

Actually, reading your question more carefully, I think I have chosen a very niche example. In my case then yes, it's entanglement.

However, the general answer to

> When an interferometer creates an interference pattern a second interference pattern is always created. The two patterns are opposites of each other.

does *not* need quantum entanglement. 
 The opposite nature of the two patterns is because of the $\pi$ phase shift that light that is reflected receives wrt to the one that is transmitted. 
 All classical.

Comment: Thanks to your answer I will always view this phenomenon with greater appreciation and understanding.

Comment: Why do we entangle the paths?  Is it not the photons that become entangled .... i.e. like in 2 photon emission (parametric downconversion).?

Comment: In my example I specifically chose just one photon. This is just a beam-splitter, there is no crystal and non-linear process going on.

Comment: Actually; reading your question more carefully, I have made an edit. Let me know if you have any questions.